# About Verbs that can be followed by object + infinitive

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

For instance, "The concepts in the next chapter should help persuade them." 
And then, englishgrammer.org explain this, "Some verbs are followed by object + infinitive without to. Examples are: let, make, see, hear, feel, watch, notice, have etc."
I would like to see more examples of words like "persuade".
Also, Can I take out "to" on any infinitive verb? Or only on some.

Comment: The question seems a little muddled, I'm afraid. The verb which is not followed by *to* here is ***help;** them* is the object of *persuade*. One might say "A bag might help carry them", but *help* is a verb which can be used with or without *to*: "A bag might help to carry them; these concepts should help to persuade them." Note the order of englishgrammar's comment: Some verbs are followed by **object + infinitive,** not "followed by bare infinitive and its object". What are you **actually** asking about here?

Comment: Thanks. I am asking two things: 1) I would like to look some other examples without "to" in complex phrase not like in simple as "Why don’t you let me go? (NOT Why don’t you let me to go?)"
2) In what an occasion I can use this style, I mean without "to" on an infinitive verb. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the technical term for it, but "let" is different than "allow" or "permit" - you can say "Why don't you allow me to go" or "Am I allowed to go", I would always write "Why don't you let me go". Perhaps this is because "let" is less nuanced than "allow". "Let" is a command/request "let me go" can really only mean one thing which is "allow me to be free of your control" whereas "allow" doesn't carry the same assumed usage. "Allow me go" - allow you to come and go as you please? It's not specific because it's not a command/request.

Comment: A request for a list of examples is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a request for a list of examples is off-topic.